# Inheritance and hierarchy in less, what's wrong?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Why when I combine inheritance inside a hierarchy, less doesn't include all properties?

I'm trying to inherit from .btn element from bootstrap. The following code doesn't works:

```
.custom-class-wrapper {
    .custom-class {
        .btn; // Will not inherit all the properties from .btn;
    }
}
```

The following code works:

```
.custom-class-wrapper {
}
.custom-class {
    .btn; // Will inherit all properties from .btn;
}
```

Comment: Can't see any such problem happening mate. Both methods are getting all properties of `.btn`.

Comment: The most common missing stuff in cases like this is that "Bootstrap classes are *not* meant to be used as mixins" (see [this collection of links](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/cefc873a78fa12924462) for more details). So while `.custom-class-wrapper .custom-class` *does* include all the properties of the globally defined `.btn` class in both cases above, this does not make `.custom-class` to behave equally in HTML since this code does not create all the styles for several (tens of) selectors the `.btn` class used in.

Comment: Ok, Bootstrap is not as extensible as I thought on first glance. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i do understand there should not be any difference between the two methods in your example. Also i agree with @harry that both methods generates all (expected) properties. Also @seven-phases-max is right, in the comments above, but the limitations mentioned do not seem to be true for your use case.

You should possible explain in your question what properties are missing or what does not act as expected.

Notice that the `.btn` class is intend to apply on only  `a` or `button` elements.

Bootstrap also defines relations for the `.btn` for instance in `button-groups.less`. These properties only are applied when the `.btn` class has been wrapped inside a `.button-group`. Your mixin does not inherit these relations. The preceding possible can be fixed by using the [extend feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature). Also notice the usage of the `all` keyword with the extend feature.

Consider for instance the `less/badges.less` which contains the following code:

```
  .badge {
  // Quick fix for badges in buttons
  .btn & {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
  }
  }
```

For the above `.custom-class:extend(.btn) {};` does not generate any output, but `.custom-class:extend(.btn all) {};` generates:

```
.custom-class .badge {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
```